# listview selectedItemTemplate doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, selecteditem

Following webproject-listview shows all views from the AdventureWorksDW2012 sample database with connection strings managed within web.config

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnSelectedIndexChanging="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging">
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
            <td><asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="xtypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("xtype") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="uidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("uid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="infoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("info") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="base_schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("base_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="replinfoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("replinfo") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="parent_objLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("parent_obj") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="crdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("crdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ftcatidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ftcatid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="stats_schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("stats_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="typeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("type") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="userstatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="sysstatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sysstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="indexdelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("indexdel") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="refdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("refdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="versionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("version") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="deltrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("deltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="instrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("instrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="updtrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("updtrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="seltrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("seltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="categoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="cacheLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cache") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#ff0000;color: grey;">
            <td><asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Aktualisieren" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Abbrechen" /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="idLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="xtypeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("xtype") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="uidTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="infoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("info") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="statusTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="base_schema_verTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("base_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="replinfoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("replinfo") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="parent_objTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("parent_obj") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="crdateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("crdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="ftcatidTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ftcatid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="schema_verTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="stats_schema_verTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("stats_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="typeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("type") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="userstatTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("userstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="sysstatTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sysstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="indexdelTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("indexdel") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="refdateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("refdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="versionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("version") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="deltrigTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("deltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="instrigTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("instrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="updtrigTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("updtrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="seltrigTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("seltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="categoryTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("category") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="cacheTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cache") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" style="background-color: grey;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
            <tr>
                <td>Keine Daten vorhanden.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td><asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Einfügen" />
                <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Löschen" /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="idTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="xtypeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("xtype") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="uidTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("uid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="infoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("info") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="statusTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="base_schema_verTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("base_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="replinfoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("replinfo") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="parent_objTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("parent_obj") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="crdateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("crdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="ftcatidTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ftcatid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="schema_verTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="stats_schema_verTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("stats_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="typeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("type") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="userstatTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("userstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="sysstatTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sysstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="indexdelTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("indexdel") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="refdateTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("refdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="versionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("version") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="deltrigTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("deltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="instrigTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("instrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="updtrigTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("updtrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="seltrigTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("seltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="categoryTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("category") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="cacheTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cache") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
            <td><asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="xtypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("xtype") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="uidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("uid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="infoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("info") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="base_schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("base_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="replinfoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("replinfo") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="parent_objLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("parent_obj") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="crdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("crdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ftcatidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ftcatid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="stats_schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("stats_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="typeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("type") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="userstatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="sysstatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sysstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="indexdelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("indexdel") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="refdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("refdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="versionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("version") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="deltrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("deltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="instrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("instrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="updtrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("updtrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="seltrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("seltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="categoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="cacheLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cache") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate><!-- textfarbe überschriften -->
        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: grey;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr runat="server" style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color:black;">
                            <th runat="server">name</th>
                            <th runat="server">id</th>
                            <th runat="server">xtype</th>
                            <th runat="server">uid</th>
                            <th runat="server">info</th>
                            <th runat="server">status</th>
                            <th runat="server">base_schema_ver</th>
                            <th runat="server">replinfo</th>
                            <th runat="server">parent_obj</th>
                            <th runat="server">crdate</th>
                            <th runat="server">ftcatid</th>
                            <th runat="server">schema_ver</th>
                            <th runat="server">stats_schema_ver</th>
                            <th runat="server">type</th>
                            <th runat="server">userstat</th>
                            <th runat="server">sysstat</th>
                            <th runat="server">indexdel</th>
                            <th runat="server">refdate</th>
                            <th runat="server">version</th>
                            <th runat="server">deltrig</th>
                            <th runat="server">instrig</th>
                            <th runat="server">updtrig</th>
                            <th runat="server">seltrig</th>
                            <th runat="server">category</th>
                            <th runat="server">cache</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="text-align: center;background-color: #CCCCCC;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #000000;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color:#ff0000;font-weight: bold;color: grey;">
            <td><asp:Label ID="nameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="xtypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("xtype") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="uidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("uid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="infoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("info") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="statusLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("status") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="base_schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("base_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="replinfoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("replinfo") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="parent_objLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("parent_obj") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="crdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("crdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="ftcatidLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ftcatid") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="stats_schema_verLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("stats_schema_ver") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="typeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("type") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="userstatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="sysstatLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sysstat") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="indexdelLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("indexdel") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="refdateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("refdate") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="versionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("version") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="deltrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("deltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="instrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("instrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="updtrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("updtrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="seltrigLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("seltrig") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="categoryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="cacheLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cache") %>' /></td>
        </tr>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I want to use the selectedItemTemplate to show the currently marked/selected item-cell with a red background so I edited the selectedItemTemplates background color to #ff0000

Following this tutorial http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=8684558 
this is in my CodeBehind:

```
    private void BindData()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Adventureworks"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM sysobjects where xtype = 'V'";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, constr);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(table);

        ListView1.DataSource = table;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {

        ListView1.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;
        string selected = ListView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
        //string selected = ListView1.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString(); 
        Label1.Text = "Selected ID: " + selected;
        BindData();

    }
```

Somehow this code doesn't work at all. If I select something nothing is changed at all, but following the code the background of the cell should be colored red.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: got a function for gridviews: RowDatabound-function:             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover",
            "this.style.backgroundColor='#7f7fff'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout",
            "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");
            } - can anyone "translate" that for listViews? RowDatabound isn't working for ListView and I don't want to use Javascript

Comment: If the question is unclear: I want to have something like an "onclick" for my listview table rows. That onclick should not work with javascript and it has to swap the background-color of the clicked row.